# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: quit in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am trying to run automation script based on selenium using python.

I am getting below error when I am trying to run script.There seems to be issue with driver.quit(), although driver.quit works perfectly in Internet Explorer but it is erroring out in Firefox. I have searched for this error but not many results came so creating this question. Below script seems to work at times but usually fails. As the error message does not give much idea as to why this is occuring, I would appreciate if someone could help me out.

---

System Details:

```
Python version = 3.6.2
Firefox version = 53 32-bit
Selenium = 3.4.3 
Geckodriver = 0.18.0 32-bit
```

---

Code Block:

```
os.environ['PATH']=r'P:\imran-TEMS\selenium-3.4.3'
user_id=getpass.getuser()
location = "C:\\Users\\" + user_id + "\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" 
binary = FirefoxBinary(location)
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy',"proxy1")
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ftp',"proxy1")
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl',"proxy1")
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks',"proxy1")
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port',8080)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ftp_port',8080)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl_port',8080)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port',8080)
profile.update_preferences()

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,firefox_binary=binary)
driver.get(link) # I have not mentioned link due to client privacy
link1=  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "access-number")))
link1.click()
link1.send_keys('14188768')

link1=  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'securityNumber')))
link1.click()
link1.send_keys('2468')

link1=  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'internet-password')))
link1.click()
link1.send_keys('test12')

sleep(1)
link1.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
sleep(2)
link2=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"id('header')/div[1]/p[1]/a[1]/span[1]")))
link2.click()


driver.quit()
```

---

Error Stack Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\imran-TEMS\script\test.py", line 54, in <module>
    driver.quit()
  File "C:\Users\l096535\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.4.3-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 181, in quit
    RemoteWebDriver.quit(self)
  File "C:\Users\l096535\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.4.3-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 551, in quit
    self.execute(Command.QUIT)
  File "C:\Users\l096535\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.4.3-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\l096535\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.4.3-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: quit
```

Comment: You should format the traceback in a separate code block.

Comment: Consider bumping up Selenium to v3.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think updating your browser to latest version might help you, I am not sure though.

Comment: I never thought answer would be this simple. Thanks a bunch :)